# Update EF from an object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I know to update an object in EF I can do something like...

```
var hotel = context.Hotels.SingleOrDefault(u => u.HotelID == editedHotel.HotelID);
    hotel.Name= editedHotel.Name;
    hotel.Address = editedHotel.Address;
    hotel.RoomCount = editedHotel.RoomCount;
context.SaveChanges();
```

but this gets quite long if a lot of fields need updating.

Is there a way I can do something like...

```
    var hotel = context.Hotels.SingleOrDefault(u => u.HotelID == editedHotel.HotelID);
hotel = editedHotel;
context.SaveChanges();
```

...so all of the fields can be changed in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about...

```
var cachedHotel = context.Hotels.Local
    .FirstOrDefault(h => h.id = editedHotel.id);
if (cachedHotel != null)
{
  context.Hotels.Detach(cachedHotel);
}
context.Hotels.Attach(editedHotel);
context.Entry(editedHotel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: May need to detach the current object from the local cache if this isn't a stateless application.   I like this answer the best because it doesn't introduce more complexity, and instead uses the features of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to look into something like AutoMapper.

However, if you override the reference to `hotel`, you just effectively lost the tracking that EF does for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use / write a clone method that uses reflection to apply the values from one object to another.

Or you could add a method to your Hotel class that takes a hotel object and applies the values, such as:

```
public void Apply(Hotel h)
{
    this.Name = h.Name;
    this.Address = h.Address;
    this.RoomCount = h.RoomCount;
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
var hotel = context.Hotels.SingleOrDefault(u => u.HotelID == editedHotel.HotelID);
    hotel.Apply(editedHotel);
context.SaveChanges();
```